# Get Release Version Properties Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

**I am trying to get the release version from properties in visual studio 2019**:

[[image: What I am trying to get]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvJfx.png)

I am trying to get what is highlighted in yellow. How can I do this in VS2019?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```cs
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()
```

Comment: That give me 1.0.0.0 and is 1.0.0.26